# Selenium RC not working when minimized

Tags: selenium

I am using selenium RC version 2.44 for running the test cases.The test cases starts failing as soon as I minimize Firefox browser on which the test cases are running and they start passing again as soon as I maximize the browser again.
I Appreciate the Help ... Thanks A lot in Advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Selenium RC, as I got started only about a year ago and with Selenium Grid and Webdriver.

With that, is there any reason why you'd need to minimize the browser?  What I've found is that once the browser loses focus (even with Webdriver) the test runner (server, command-line-invoked Java executable) seems to "lose connection" to the browser and I have to re-run the test again - only not allow the loss of focus.

A suggestion, perhaps use some code (if RC supports it) to change the window dimensions of Firefox (not run full screen) if you can.